# Last footer of an Exam be "End of Exam"

Tags: header-footer, exam

I am using the `exam` class.

I am writing an exam, and I want the last footer (the final, last one to appear)  to be "End of exam".

I have this:

```latex
    \pagestyle{headandfoot}
    \runningheadrule
    \firstpageheader{AP Calculus Practice Exam A1}{ Mao Laoshi }{Senior 2}
    \firstpageheadrule
    \runningheader{AP Calculus Practice Exam A1}
    { Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
    {Senior 2 }

    \footer{}
    {\iflastpage{End of exam}{Please go on to the next page\ldots}}
    {}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
\iflastpage{<text 1>}{<text 2>}
```

inside `\footer`. `<text 1>` will be used in the last page, and `<text 2>` will be used in all other pages, except the last one; a simple example, now including the settings of the edited question:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[paperheight=12cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text for the example

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{AP Calculus Practice Exam A1}{ Mao Laoshi }{Senior 2}
\firstpageheadrule
\runningheader{AP Calculus Practice Exam A1}
{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
{Senior 2}
\footer{}
{\iflastpage{End of exam}{Please go on to the next page\ldots}}
{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the \lipsum[1-30] do I have to know how many pages before the end?

Comment: @MaoYiyi no; `\lipsum[30]` only generates some pages with "dummy" text and you don't have to use it in your actual document; `\iflastpage` automatically will detect the last page.

Comment: @MaoYiyi in your document all you need to add is something like `\footer{}
{\iflastpage{End of exam}{Please go on to the next page\ldots}}
{}` in the preamble.

Comment: Your solutoin gave me a runaway footer issue, but answer below worked?   I have none idea why.

Comment: @MaoYiyi did you try the exact code I posted? Did you get the error with that code or with your actual code?

Comment: @MaoYiyi most probably you forgot a pair of braces from my answer.

Comment: Yes, latex treats me like the tamborine at a pentacosta church.

Comment: @MaoYiyi so my code finally worked or are you still getting errors with it?

Comment: @MaoYiyi ah, OK. You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

One can also achieve the same result with the command `\runningfooter{<text>}{<text>}{<text>}`:

```
\runningfooter{}{\iflastpage{End of exam}{Please go on to the next page\ldots}}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
```

This allows the first page footer to be different from the rest of the pages:

```
\firstpagefooter{}{}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
```